# Different response using address versus coordinates

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

We are using *Google distance* matrix api and getting different response when using address versus coordinates for the exact same address.

When using address we don't get any information about the 
borough/postal town, we only get the municipality (higher level).

WITH ADDRESS

```
   `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json? 
   origins=Urban Hjärnes väg 18,168 58,BROMMA&destinations=Hantverkarg 67- 
   69,112 92,STOCKHOLM&mode=walking&language=sv-SE&key

    {
       "destination_addresses" : [ "Hantverkargatan 67, 112 31 Stockholm, 
        Sverige" ],
       "origin_addresses" : [ "Urban Hjärnes väg, Stockholm, Sverige" ],
       "rows" : [
          {
             "elements" : [
                {
                   "distance" : {
                   "text" : "8,0 km",
                   "value" : 7970
                   },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 tim 41 min",
                  "value" : 6031
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
    ],
   "status" : "OK"
    }
```

`
WITH COORDINATES

```
    `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json? 
   units=metric&origins=59.351563, 17.922239&destinations=Hantverkarg%2067- 
   69,112%2092,STOCKHOLM&key=

    {
    "destination_addresses" : [ "Hantverkargatan 67, 112 31 Stockholm, Sweden" ],
    "origin_addresses" : **[ "Urban Hjärnes väg 18, 168 58 Bromma, Sweden" ]** 
    ,
       "rows" : [
        {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "7.6 km",
                  "value" : 7627
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "14 mins",
                  "value" : 824
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
        }
       ],
       "status" : "OK"
    }`
```

Even when we search with the address we want 
"origin_addresses" : `[ "Urban Hjärnes väg 18, 168 58 Bromma, Sweden" ]`
instead of
"origin_addresses" : `[ "Urban Hjärnes väg, Stockholm, Sverige" ]`, which is not complete

Comment: It looks like the issue is not reproducible anymore. Using origin [string address](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=18+Urban+Hjärnes+väg,+Bromma&destinations=Hantverkarg+67-69,112+92,STOCKHOLM&key=YOUR_KEY) and [coordinates](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=59.351563,17.922239&destinations=Hantverkarg+67-69,112+92,STOCKHOLM&key=YOUR_KEY), both returns the same origin_address of "Urban Hjärnes väg 18, 168 58 Bromma, Sweden".

Comment: We have updated the first url which was wrong. We still do not get the right origin_addresses. We expect 'Bromma' instead of 'Stockholm' as in the example with coodinates

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the issue using the ff addresses:

Correct results: ["Urban Hjärnes väg 18, 168 58 Bromma, Sweden"](https://www.google.com/maps/search/Urban+Hj%C3%A4rnes+v%C3%A4g+18,+168+58+Bromma,+Sweden)

```
Urban Hjärnes väg 18
168 58 Bromma
Sweden
```

Incorrect results: ["Urban Hjärnes väg 18,168 58 Bromma, Sweden"](https://www.google.com/maps/search/Urban+Hj%C3%A4rnes+v%C3%A4g+18,168+58+Bromma,+Sweden)

```
Urban Hjärnes väg
Stockholm
Sweden
```

Notice that you can have the expected results when querying the address with proper spaces between the street number "18," and postal code "168 58". So as a workaround, you can use this sample request:

[`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Urban+Hjärnes+väg+18,+168+58+Bromma,+Sweden&destinations=Hantverkarg+67-69,+112+92+STOCKHOLM&mode=walking&language=sv-SE&key=API_KEY`](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Urban+Hj%C3%A4rnes+v%C3%A4g+18,+168+58+Bromma,+Sweden&destinations=Hantverkarg+67-69,+112+92+STOCKHOLM&mode=walking&language=sv-SE&key=API_KEY)

Which correctly returns the expected address:

```
{
    destination_addresses: [
        "Hantverkargatan 67, 112 31 Stockholm, Sverige"
    ],
    origin_addresses: [
        "Urban Hjärnes väg 18, 168 58 Bromma, Sverige"
    ],
    rows: [
        {
            elements: [
                {
                    distance: {
                        text: "8,0 km",
                        value: 7976
                    },
                    duration: {
                        text: "1 tim 41 min",
                        value: 6036
                    },
                    status: "OK"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    status: "OK"
}
```

You can also then file this issue in Google's [Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#issue_tracker) for their engineering team to further investigate.

Hope this helps!